# How would Arnold Potterley blackmail Foster if necessary?

Tags: the-dead-past

In Isaac Asimov's "The Dead Past", how would Arnold blackmail Foster?

As seen in these lines:

> Let the youngster gather knowledge. Let him think a small gathering would be his limit. Having taken the path to anarchy, there would be no limit. If the boy were not driven onward by something in himself, the first steps would be error enough to force the rest. **Potterley was quite certain he would not hesitate to use blackmail.** Potterley waved a last good-by and looked up. It was beginning to rain. Certainly! **Blackmail if necessary, but he would not be stopped.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, Potterley would be blackmailing Foster with having already started into forbidden activity. While research into neutrinics and the chronoscope is not apparently illegal, such research is seen as frivolous and there is an unspoken threat that a researcher, and thereby the university he works for, would have all research funding cut off if they were found to be trying to "waste" resources in that manner. If Potterley were to inform the university that Foster was investigating neutrinics, then they might fire him to avoid being tainted by association and similarly, future universities would be loathe to hire him.

Potterley, for his part, has less to lose in a manner of speaking. He has essentially lost his wife to her grief over their lost daughter, and he feels unable to pursue his academic goals without the chronoscope, so he's more willing to take the risk.

Comment: In the story, the problem isn't specific to neutrinics and the chronoscope.  All research is done on approved subjects.  It is a form of "academic misconduct" to carry out research on a subject that isn't approved and to which you haven't been assigned.  Foster could have worked on (and found) a cure for cancer, and he still would have gotten in trouble for carrying out unapproved research.  Potterly would have blackmailed Foster for unapproved research rather than the neutrinics specifically.